# Keycloak: map ldap groups to springboot roles

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Our company users are stored in ldap (oracle internet directory). Users have certain groups, e.g. Administrators, Users etc.
I need to map those groups to my client application roles. Client application is test Spring Boot app with keycloak-spring-security-adapter ([pom](https://pastebin.com/ja5TPzWH)).

Steps I made in Keycloak admin console:

1. In Users Federation menu create user federation with ldap (without import). Check that ldap users can be found in Users menu.
2. Add group-ldap-mapper https://prnt.sc/12fb6b8 Check that ldap groups are visible in Groups menu. Also users have correct group membership: https://prnt.sc/12fb9xr
3. In Clients create client for my application.
4. In client create two roles - ADMIN and USER: https://prnt.sc/12fbbut
5. In Groups - Administrators (ldap group) - Role Mappings add ADMIN client role: http://prntscr.com/12fbhbq Do same for USER. Now my user in Users menu have correct effective roles, including ADMIN and USER: https://prnt.sc/12fc7j2

Create simple Spring Boot app with KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter: https://pastebin.com/HsHuNn55
And application.yml: https://pastebin.com/JPFmwKyS

Now I access my client application in a browser and get redirected to keycloak, where I authenticate with my ldap user password.
I expect authenticated user to have ADMIN role within application. But actually it only have standard keycloak roles and not my custom roles created in client: https://prnt.sc/12fc3fx Controller methods with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` respond with 403.

What am I missing?
Thanks. Keycloak 12.0.3, Spring Boot 2.4.2

---

upd:

I've made http request to keycloak auth endpoint outside my client app (using http client) and in received access token I do see my custom ADMIN and USER roles in `resource_access` section:

```
"realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "adapter-client-test": {
      "roles": [
        "ADMIN",
        "USER"
      ]
    },
```

So I believe keycloak itself is configured correctly but something's wrong with spring boot client application?

Comment: Try adding a mapper of type "User Client Role" under your client. The following answers a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354754/how-to-get-the-roles-in-access-token-keycloak/62359540#62359540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns outs, the one thing I missed was `keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings: true` in application.yml.

From [doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/):

> use-resource-role-mappings
> If set to true, the adapter will look inside the token for application level role mappings for the user. If false, it will look at the realm level for user role mappings. This is OPTIONAL. The default value is false.

After that application authenticated user received custom client-level roles.